# NullPointerException with TCP Connection

Tags: java, android, tcp, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement a TCP connection for one of my projects. Following a few tutorials I found an example that is used quite often. I've been trying to make it work but even in a minimalistic project I'm getting an NullPointerException.

The Code for my MainActivity is as following:

```
package f.l.tcptest;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TcpClient mTcpClient;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new ConnectTask().execute("");

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("testing");

            }
        });

    }




    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object
            TcpClient mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });

            mTcpClient.run();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //response received from server
            Log.d("test", "response " + values[0]);
            //process server response here....

        }




    }
}
```

And for the TCPClient:

```
package f.l.tcptest;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class TcpClient {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.102"; //server IP address
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 1337;
    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;
    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;
    // used to send messages
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(final String message) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mBufferOut != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sending: " + message);
                    mBufferOut.println(message + "\r\n");
                    mBufferOut.flush();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }



    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

            try {

                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {

                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }

}
```

When i start the app, it connects to the server and maintains the connection. If i press the button to send the test message the app crashes and shows the following:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                         Process: f.l.tcptest, PID: 16391
>                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void f.l.tcptest.TcpClient.sendMessage(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                             at f.l.tcptest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
>                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: the linked answer was interesting and helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared the field in your activity, but you never initialize it. Check your AsyncTask's **doInBackground** method. You are creating a ***new local field*** called **mTcpClient**, you are not accessing the MainActivity's field. This is why you got NullPointException.

Here is the fixed code:

```
package f.l.tcptest;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TcpClient mTcpClient;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new ConnectTask().execute("");

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    mTcpClient.sendMessage("testing");
            }
        });

    }

    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {
            //we create a TCPClient object
            // You should use the global one, do not create the local instance if you want to use it on click event
           mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //response received from server
            Log.d("test", "response " + values[0]);
            //process server response here....
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional Note for Android:**

But this approach is not good. You should follow best practices. Maybe you can use the intent service instead of AsyncTasks and sending message on UI thread.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding!